# Как расшифровать AES-256 на PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angular, aes

Я шифрую данные в Angular:

```
 this.conversionEncryptOutput = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(this.data.trim(), this.publicKey.trim()).toString();
```

И отправляю на сервер(PHP), где их и расшифровываю:

```
 $decryte = openssl_decrypt($crypte, "aes-256-cbc", "key");
```

Но в результате сервер выдает false.
**Что я делаю не правильно?**

Comment: $crypte не в base64

Comment: `openssl_decrypt($crypte, "aes-256-cbc", "key", false, "key");` а так?

Comment: Warning openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is 19 bytes long which is longer than the 16 expected by selected cipher

Comment: `openssl_decrypt($crypte, "aes-256-cbc", "key", false, mb_substr("key", 0, 16));`

Comment: Результат: false

Comment: Есть пример данных? ($crypte)

Comment: 7StScX3LnPUly/VNzBes0w==